# Create Database in SQL Cloud second generation

Tags: mysql

How to create a new database of MySQL in second generation of Google Cloud MySQL. I have created a instance of MySQL Second Generation on Google Cloud. I cannot find a link to create a new database in the instance. How do I create a new database.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the Create a New Database link either, and here is how I got around it last night:

Go to your console, then select your instance, then select your project. In the Instance Details screen, in the upper right corner, click Activate Google Cloud Shell. This brings up an interface on the bottom of the screen.

Type in the following, custom to your instance name/user: 
gcloud beta sql connect YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME --user root

Then hit Enter. Enter your password. If anything weird happens, you may need to whitelist your local IP, though using Google Cloud Shell, you may not need to. Forget what I did.

Then enter the following, custom to your needs, and hit Enter: 
CREATE DATABASE guestbook;

This creates a database named guestbook in your SQL instance. From there - this is what I found easiest - I used a MySQL client to connect to the cloud database (be sure to whitelist your IP) and then added columns that way. I believe I added a table using Cloud SQL as well.

This link (see Connecting to an Instance) https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/getting-started?hl=en
 helped me out.